# microsoft access executable form

Tags: ms-access

Good day people, I have created this form in Access, so my question is, Is there anywhere to make this form only show the form itself (Mainfrm) without opening up access. In other word i want to see only the part in Yellow box when i open this file. I have disable navigations and i have compiled it to ACCDE but it still open up Microsoft Access when ever i open it.
Thank you, please see the image below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3bpu.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot start your application (it surely consists of more than a form, what about tables?) without Access, but you can hide almost all of its User Interface, except the title bar.

See this answer by Albert D. Kallal: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24638829/3820271

Comment: Thank you Albert, i am going through the thread right now, i will come back with a question if i run into trouble.

Comment: Thank You, the Link Helped. I guess this question can be Considered Answered.