# Is it possible to change an .accde file icon to a custom image?

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to make my Access (2013) application look less like Access and more like a "real" piece of software. One of the things I am trying to accomplish is changing the icon from the normal A/grid/lock to an image of my choosing.

Is this possible? If not really, what is my next best option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the icon that Access shows when running your database, it's under Options -> Current database.

You cannot change the icon that Explorer shows for your .accde file.

Of course you can create a shortcut with the commandline to MSACCESS.EXE and your database, and that shortcut can have a custom icon.

You may also be interested in this answer by Albert D. Kallal: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24638829/3820271

Comment: The shortcut method would work well, but I need to distribute the .accde to multiple users and can't make a shortcut for each of them. The back end is in a SQL Server, so I just send the front-end through email. Do I need to look into using an installer?

Comment: @Mike: An installer would perhaps be overkill. You can put the db, the icon and the shortcut into a zip and distribute this, with the instruction to extract it to a fixed folder (so that the shortcut and the icon work). And to copy the shortcut to the desktop. If you have a network share everyone can access, this can be automated with a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

I just developed this method yesterday to allow an Access Executable to have a custom icon.  It does involve making some additions to your computer's registry.   Be aware I did this for Access 2010 on a Windows 7 machine.  I have not tested this for windows 8 or 10, but I do think it will be the same.

I know the entries of .14 ONLY refer to Access 2010.  Access 2013 should be .15 and Access 2016 should be .16.

When you export your "accde" registry entries to a .reg file, stick with the .14, .15, or .16 that is exported for your specific system.  The only thing you will be changing is any occurrence of "accde" to "accxx" with the "xx" being your new letters for your chosen suffix for the Access executable database.

Below is the .reg file that will perform the registry "fixes" and I have included a few notes along the way.  This is not for the beginner, but I do believe a seasoned Access developer should be able to follow.  Are you a little uncomfortable with the registry?  Use Google to help you find a write-up or two about the registry and how to make changes to the registry.

OK, the .reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.accVR]
"Content Type"="application/msaccess.exec"
@="Access.ACCVRFile.14"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.accVR\Access.ACCVRFile.14]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.accVR\Access.ACCVRFile.14\ShellNew]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\
FileExts\.accVR]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\
 FileExts\.accVR\OpenWithList]
"a"="MSACCESS.EXE"
"MRUList"="a"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\
FileExts\.accVR\OpenWithProgids]
"Access.accVRFile.14"=hex(0):

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Access.ACCVRFile.14]
@="Microsoft Access ACCVR Database"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Access.ACCVRFile.14\CLSID]
@="{73A4C9C1-D68D-11D0-98BF-00A0C90DC8D9}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Access.ACCVRFile.14\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\_Work\\VR\\VR Logo.ico"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Access.ACCVRFile.14\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Access.ACCVRFile.14\shell\Open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Access.ACCVRFile.14\shell\Open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\MSACCESS.EXE\"  /NOSTARTUP \"%1\" %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9"
"command"=hex (7):79,00,6b,00,47,00,5e,00,56,00,35,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,\
21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,4d,00,4b,00,4b,00,53,00,6b,00,41,00,43,00,43,\
00,45,00,53,00,53,00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,3e,00,32,00,41,00,5a,00,\
7e,00,60,00,4f,00,37,00,71,00,43,00,3f,00,4f,00,57,00,2c,00,66,00,65,00,5a,\
00,79,00,63,00,78,00,68,00,20,00,2f,00,4e,00,4f,00,53,00,54,00,41,00,52,00,\
54,00,55,00,50,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,20,00,25,00,32,00,20,00,25,\
00,33,00,20,00,25,00,34,00,20,00,25,00,35,00,20,00,25,00,36,00,20,00,25,00,\
37,00,20,00,25,00,38,00,20,00,25,00,39,00,00,00,00,00
```

From top line down:

- Any .reg file has to start with the correct name of the regedit.exe you will be dealing with.  In this case I am dealing with Windows 7, therefore version 5.00.
  The rest of the code in this file came straight out of the registry.
- Within `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT]` I scrolled down to the entry `".accde"`
- Right click on this and select the `"Export"` option from the drop down menu.
- Provide the folder and file name to export to.

Now you need to do the same within `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER]`.  Here you will need to:

- Scroll to Software, then Microsoft, then Windows, then CurrentVersion, then Explorer, then FileExts, and finally .accde.
- Right click, select Export, etc.
- And lastly, within the [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT] scroll to "Access.ACCDEFile.14"
- Right click on this and select the "Export" option, provide the saving info and save the file.

Put these three files together, leaving out the Windows Registry Editor Version line from the second and third files.

What I did from here was to create my own suffix rather than use the Microsoft .accde.  I used the initials of the company this software is being written for.  In this example, I will just use my own initials, VR.  Keeping the ".acc" and just changing the "de" to whatever I will be using for the new suffix in order to use my custom icon.

You do not need to stay with only two characters.
In this new .reg file, carefully work your way through the file changing the "de" (or "DE") within any accordance of "accde" (or "ACCDE") you find.

For example, one of the places you will find "ACCDE" is in the string "[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Access.ACCDEFile.14"  Change the "DE" to "VR" (for this  example) giving you the new string "[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Access.ACCVRFile.14"

When you are finished, I suggest you search for the string "accde" within the file to be sure you have changed them all to the new suffix you are going to use. 
**Before using this .reg file to update your registry, BACKUP YOUR REGISTRY!!!**

Comment: Interesting approach.  I'll have to try this sometime.

Comment: One of the nice things about this approach is that if you have multiple executable Access DBs, each one can have its own suffix and therefore its own custom icon too.