# Hiding the navigation pane

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

OK, so I need to hide the navigation pane but struggling.

I am using a module to hide it and have tried the following but to no avail:

```
DoCmd.NavigateTo "acNavigationCategoryObjectType"
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdWindowHide
```

I have also tried:

```
 DoCmd.SelectObject acTable, , False
```

Neither are working - Any ideas?

Comment: Just untick the option? https://stackoverflow.com/a/24638829/3820271

Comment: That first option works for me. Can you elaborate on what doesn't work? Does it give an error? How are you running it?

Comment: The first option only works reliably if no other objects are open. If there is a default form, add it to the Form_Load event for that form.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
 DoCmd.SelectObject acTable, , True
 DoCmd.RunCommand (acCmdWindowHide)
```

if that doesn't work, use a table name that exists instead of skipping that second argument in docmd.selectobject

Answer (score 1):

**HideNavPane()**

I found that the code suggested in other examples would fail if a search filter was currently set in the navigation pane.  In some cases this would cause the active form to close.  That can lead to a bad user experience.  This routine should get around that.

```vb
Public Sub HideNavPane()
' This will hide the Navigation Pane.
' It works even if a search filter is set, unlike other solutions that may
' inadvertently close the active object.
' Limitations:  An object (form, report, query, etc) must be open and it 
'               cannot be the same name as the selected item in the nav pane
'               or this will do nothing.
  
    Dim strCurrentObjectName As String
    
    strCurrentObjectName = Application.CurrentObjectName
      
    ' Move focus to the navigation pane/database container
    DoCmd.NavigateTo ("acNavigationCategoryObjectType")
  
    If strCurrentObjectName <> Application.CurrentObjectName Then
        ' The Navigation Pane is open and has focus.
        ' Use the window menu to hide the navigation pane
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdWindowHide
    End If
  
End Sub
```