# How to programmatically show the Navigation Panel?

Tags: ms-access

If I open Access normally (and let the startup scripts run), then hit F11, I get the Navigation Panel, but the context menu doesn't come up on a right click.

If I open Access with the Shift Key, the context menu works as expected.

I'm attempting to write a function in VBS that will execute on startup and effectively replace the need for the shift key.
If I use my script, Access opens, the navigation panel is visible, but no context menu.

```
If Command = "develop" Then
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "Dialog_Login"
    DoCmd.SelectObject acTable, , True    
    ...
```

This makes it impossible to edit, say, an update or delete query. The only thing I can do is open it which runs the update/delete which would be bad.

I printed out all the properties from CurrentDB after opening with shift and without. I don't see anything that is missing. But Shift allows the context menu to work and my script doesn't. I can't see what else I could be missing.

I tried doing the reverse and allowing the Navigation Panel and then hiding it when running normally. Still doesn't work. Besides the bad look of the Nav panel flashing up, the context menu still doesn't work unless I use the Shift key.

Comment: You want VBA to override db Options settings? See if any clue in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Access.Application.SetOption

Comment: Thanks for the syntax for setting Options. I don't see any options listed related to the Navigation panel.

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47475999/hiding-the-navigation-pane

Comment: I tried setting options, and that seemed to have affect some times and not other times. Turns out that it is a fool's errand because the options I set this time only take effect next time. So if you run it twice the same way, it will appear to work the second time. But then run it the other way, which worked before, and it fails the first time. Make a subtle change and it appears to work.